# Laravel controller doesn´t process my view parameters

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent, crud

Guys I really need your help.

I have this controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $books = Book::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('index', compact('books'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('add');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['titulo' => 'required', 'npaginas' => 'required', 'edicion' => 'required', 'autor' => 'required', 'resumen'=>'required', 'precio'=>'required']);
        Book::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
    public function edit($id){


        return view('edit');
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['titulo' => 'required', 'npaginas' => 'required', 'edicion' => 'required', 'autor' => 'required', 'resumen'=>'required', 'precio'=>'required']);
        book::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('book.index');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Book::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }    
}
```

I have a view sending a `id` from a `book` to the **edit** and **destroy** functions. However I am only receiving a `404 error.

This is the view:

```
@if($books->count())
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$book->titulo}}</td>
                <td>{{$book->npaginas}}</td>
                <td>{{$book->edicion}}</td>
                <td>{{$book->autor}}</td>
                <td>{{$book->resumen}}</td>
                <td>${{$book->precio}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs margen-boton"
                       href="{{ action('BookController@edit', $book->id) }}"><span
                            class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></a>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form action="{{ action('BookController@destroy', $book->id )}}"
                          method="post">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs margen-boton2" type="submit"><span
                                class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8" class="text-center"><p>Sin libros en el inventario</p></td>
        </tr>
    @endif
```

The truth is I´m changing the `book` variable name but it doesn´t do anything.

I try changing the controller name into the view cause I thought there was the problem. but that doesn´t work. I don´t really know what to do.

If you can help me, that would be awesome

Comment: do your route have a name to each of your action? ex: `Route::get('','')->name(routename)`;

Comment: can you share your route?

Comment: Not really, it is just: 
Route::resource('/', 'BookController');

Comment: Route::resource('/', 'BookController');

thats all i got in my route

Comment: just noticed that in the update method you are using 

book::find($id)->update($request->all());

instead of

Book::find($id)->update($request->all());

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/1/edit thats all i got from the view

Comment: @codeBoyCode i just change it, thanks bro, but the problem is still there

Comment: @AlbertoLópezJiménez haha cool cool - just spotted it and thought i'd let you know. I'm having a look at your problem - hopefully get an answer for you soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple example follow these steps

In your `web.php` file use this

```
Route::get("/edit/{id}", ["as" => "books.edit", "uses" => "BookController@edit"]);
```

After that here in `BookController` code should be like this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Book;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function create()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        ....
    }
    public function edit($id){


        return view('edit', [
                'id' => $id
            ]);
    }

}
```

And in your `index.blade.php` file you need to create link like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs margen-boton"
    href="{{ route('books.edit', ['id' => $book->id]) }}">

    <span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span>
</a>
```

That will work exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks bro, but it show another error :(

"Undefined variable: book (View: /Users/alberto/Projects/libreria2/resources/views/edit.blade.php)"

Into my edit view i have:

<form method="post" action="{{route('book.update',$book->id)}}" role="form">

Comment: git@gitlab.com:splash.jalj/library-stock.git 

Here is the repo, thanks so much bro

Comment: Ok. Give me 10 mints I will check and provide you solution

Comment: Don´t forget it please :(

Comment: I fixed issues. but not able to push my code on git.

Comment: download working example from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MYsnrSref3ZmYfXhKKtmf0j0-j69R1Fq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks bro, i´ll check it out